# Replace double backslashes with single backslash using JS223 processor

Tags: jmeter

I have a variable (CONTEXTTOKEN) which I extract in JMeter using a Boundary Extractor. This variable has double backslashes as below:

[image]

I am using a JS223 processor to try and replace the double backslashes with a single one like this:

```
def myVariable = vars.get("CONTEXTTOKEN") 

def request = myVariable.replaceAll("\\", "\")

vars.put("CONTEXTTOKEN", request)
```

However when I run my script CONTEXTTOKEN still has double backslashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I resolved this by doing a .toString().replace("\\\\","\\").